# The problem is/was due to something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Do normal native English speakers say `The problem is/was due to the increased amount of traffic.`?

In general, I would like to know if `is/was due to` is a common expression or there's a more natural one?

Comment: http://linguistech.ca/Tips+and+Tricks+-+Because+of+vs.+Due+to

Comment: It's fine. "Due to" is slightly more formal than some options.

Comment: You will find that **due to** was disparaged in books published in the 20th century about "proper" English writing . The preferred expression was "because of".  But that prohibition has largely been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native English speaker. To me, the phrase "is/was due/owing to increased amount of traffic", though grammatically correct, is not easy on the ear in spoken English. Instead, I'll say "because of a lot of/heavy/huge traffic".

Comment: *due* is an adjective, appropriately applied here to a noun (*problem*).  It's grating to some of us purists when applied to a **clause** rather than a noun (“We got here late due to traffic”); there, we prefer *because of*.

Answer (score 0):

**Due to** is very formal. A native speaker might use it in an academic paper, a courtroom, or a very important business meeting. For example:

- Due to a 20% increase in traffic, our service experienced 158 outage incidents this quarter.
- I am afraid that I will need to decline the invitation due to a prior commitment.
- Due to your excellent performance, you are being offered a raise of 10% of your annual salary. Congratulations!

In most cases, native speakers will say **because of** or just **because** Here are some examples:

- I can't buy any more books because my shelf is full.
- My history teacher gave me bonus points on my paper because of my very detailed research.
- You will be scheduled for an extra shift because you asked for one.